# Let $\varphi :M \to N$ be a linear map such that $\varphi(b)=f(b)$ for all $b \in B$. Show that $\varphi$ is injective iff $f(B)$ is free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ & $N$ be $R-$modules and suppose that $M$ has a base $B$ and $f:B \to N$ is some map. Let $\varphi :M \to N$ be a linear map such that $\varphi(b)=f(b)$ for all $b \in B$. Show that $\varphi$ is injective iff $f(B)$ is free.

For the first direction we suppose that $\varphi$ is injective. To show that $f(B)$ is free I need to find a basis for it? That is I need to find a $B' \subset f(B)$ such that for every subset $\{f(b_1), \dots, f(b_n)\} = \{\varphi(b_1), \dots, \varphi(b_n)\} \subset f(B)$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n r_i f(b_i)=0 \implies r_i=0  \text{ for all $i$.}$$

Now because $$0=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i f(b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i \varphi(b_i)= \varphi\left( \sum_{i=1}^n r_ib_i\right)$$ and $\varphi$ is injective we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^n r_ib_i=0$$ and because $b_i \in B$ and $B$ is a base $r_i =0$ for all $i$.

However this is only one part of the two conditions for a basis. I haven't really found $B'$ which concerns me. Is it so that $f(B)$ is itself actually a basis and therefore free?

Comment: I use "free" only for modules, not for subsets of them. What does it mean for the set $f(B)$ to be free? Do you mean $R$-linear independence? If so, do you really consider $B$ and $f(B)$ as sets or rather as families?

Comment: I think we're calling the base of a free module also "free" so I suppose what I showed is satisfactory(?). Also $B$ and $f(B)$ should be sets not families. I suppose that by family you mean a collection of sets?